# Error: IncorrectProgramId at transferCheckedWithFee

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, transfer, error

```
import {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  PublicKey,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  clusterApiUrl,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} from '@solana/web3.js';
import {
  ExtensionType,
  TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID,
  createAccount,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction,
  getMintLen,
  mintTo,
  transferCheckedWithFee,
} from '@solana/spl-token';
import fs from 'fs';

// Connection to devnet cluster
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl('devnet'), 'confirmed');

// Main Wallet
const payer = createKeyPairFromJSON('./wallets/main.json');
const mint_auth = createKeyPairFromJSON('./wallets/mint_auth.json');
const test_1 = createKeyPairFromJSON('./wallets/test_1.json');
const test_2 = createKeyPairFromJSON('./wallets/test_2.json');
const test_3 = createKeyPairFromJSON('./wallets/test_3.json');

// Transaction signature returned from sent transaction
let transactionSignature: string;

// Fee basis points for transfers (100 = 1%)
const feeBasisPoints = 1000;

// Maximum fee for transfers in token base units
const maxFee = BigInt(100);

// Decimals for Mint Account
const decimals = 9;

async function create_mint_account() {
  // Generate new keypair for Mint Account
  const mintKeypair = Keypair.generate();
  // Address for Mint Account
  const mint = mintKeypair.publicKey;
  // Authority that can mint new tokens
  const mintAuthority = payer;
  // Authority that can modify transfer fees
  const transferFeeConfigAuthority = payer;
  // Authority that can move tokens withheld on mint or token accounts
  const withdrawWithheldAuthority = payer;

  // Size of Mint Account with extensions
  const mintLen = getMintLen([ExtensionType.TransferFeeConfig]);

  // Minimum lamports required for Mint Account
  const lamports = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(mintLen);

  // Instruction to invoke System Program to create new account
  const createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: payer.publicKey, // Account that will transfer lamports to created account
    newAccountPubkey: mint, // Address of the account to create
    space: mintLen, // Amount of bytes to allocate to the created account
    lamports, // Amount of lamports transferred to created account
    programId: TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID, // Program assigned as owner of created account
  });

  // Instruction to initialize TransferFeeConfig Extension
  const initializeTransferFeeConfig =
    createInitializeTransferFeeConfigInstruction(
      mint, // Mint Account address
      transferFeeConfigAuthority.publicKey, // Authority to update fees
      withdrawWithheldAuthority.publicKey, // Authority to withdraw fees
      feeBasisPoints, // Basis points for transfer fee calculation
      maxFee, // Maximum fee per transfer
      TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
    );

  // Instruction to initialize Mint Account data
  const initializeMintInstruction = createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mint, // Mint Account Address
    decimals, // Decimals of Mint
    mintAuthority.publicKey, // Designated Mint Authority
    null, // Optional Freeze Authority
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
  );

  // Add instructions to new transaction
  const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    createAccountInstruction,
    initializeTransferFeeConfig,
    initializeMintInstruction
  );

  // Send transaction
  transactionSignature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
    connection,
    transaction,
    [payer, mintKeypair] // Signers
  );

  console.log(
    '\nCreate Mint Account:',
    `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
  );

  return mintKeypair;
}

async function create_token_account(mint: PublicKey) {
  const sourceTokenAccount = await createAccount(
    connection,
    payer, // Payer to create Token Account
    mint, // Mint Account address
    payer.publicKey, // Token Account owner
    undefined, // Optional keypair, default to Associated Token Account
    undefined, // Confirmation options
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
  );

  return sourceTokenAccount;
}

async function mint_tokens(
  mint: PublicKey,
  sourceTokenAccount: PublicKey,
  amount: number
) {
  // Mint 100 tokens to Playground wallet
  await mintTo(
    connection,
    payer,
    mint, // Mint Account address
    sourceTokenAccount, // Destination Token Account
    payer.publicKey,
    amount, // Number of tokens to mint
    [],
    undefined, // Confirmation options
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
  );
}

async function transfer_tokens(
  mint: PublicKey,
  sourceAccount: PublicKey,
  destinationAccount: PublicKey,
  amount: bigint
) {
  // Calculate transfer fee
  const fee = (amount * BigInt(feeBasisPoints)) / BigInt(10_000);
  // Determine fee charged
  const feeCharged = fee > maxFee ? maxFee : fee;

  // Transfer tokens with fee
  transactionSignature = await transferCheckedWithFee(
    connection,
    payer, // Transaction fee payer
    sourceAccount, // Source Token Account
    mint, // Mint Account address
    destinationAccount, // Destination Token Account
    payer.publicKey, // Owner of Source Account
    amount, // Amount to transfer
    decimals, // Mint Account decimals
    feeCharged, // Transfer fee
    [], // Additional signers
    undefined, // Confirmation options
    TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID // Token Extension Program ID
  );

  console.log(
    '\nTransfer Tokens:',
    `https://solana.fm/tx/${transactionSignature}?cluster=devnet-solana`
  );
}

async function main() {
  console.log('Creating mint account...');
  const mint = await create_mint_account();
  console.log(mint);

  console.log('Creating token account...');
  const sourceTokenAccount = await create_token_account(mint.publicKey);
  console.log(sourceTokenAccount);

  console.log('Minting tokens...');
  await mint_tokens(mint.publicKey, sourceTokenAccount, 1000000000000000);

  console.log('Transferring tokens...');
  console.log(payer.publicKey.toString());
  await transfer_tokens(
    mint.publicKey,
    sourceTokenAccount,
    test_1.publicKey,
    BigInt(100000)
  );
}

main();

function createKeyPairFromJSON(path: string) {
  return Keypair.fromSecretKey(
    new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path).toString()))
  );
}
```

Creating and minting works just fine, but when i want to transfer it I get the following Error:

```
SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (/Users/benjaminarand/dev/me/solana/T2022/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5922:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (/Users/benjaminarand/dev/me/solana/T2022/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5881:20)
    at async Connection.sendTransaction (/Users/benjaminarand/dev/me/solana/T2022/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5869:12)
    at async sendAndConfirmTransaction (/Users/benjaminarand/dev/me/solana/T2022/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/utils/send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:35:21) {
  logs: [
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [1]',
    'Program log: TransferFeeInstruction: TransferCheckedWithFee',
    'Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 7147 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: incorrect program id for instruction'
  ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

The program id stays always the same.
Did anyone have the same error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The check that fails checks that both the source and destination accounts are owned by `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID`. Make sure the destination account is a token account owned by `TOKEN_2022_PROGRAM_ID`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a transaction to create the destination token account.

It looks like you're using `test_1.publicKey` as the address of the recipient token account, but no token account was created using the address.

Here is a [guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/transfer-fee) you can reference.